# Seeking inspiration - are there professional watercolor pencil artists and if no - why not?

Tags: watercolor, colored-pencils, pencils

I like watercolor pencil technique very much. Are there professional artists that work in watercolor pencil tehnique. If no - then why not? Soft pastels and soft pastel pencils are accepted and rather widely used medium by professional artists. What about watercolor pencils?

I would be happy to get inspiration for my own efforts and to be sure that my efforts using watercolor pencils have perspective to achieve more higher level of acceptance as art.

Comment: Selling art has much to do with how well you talk people into buying it as with the quality of the art itself, medium is the least of the problems. (Unless it makes you feel unsure and in that case I wonder if you have the 'it' that makes you a prof.

Answer (score 2):

Look up Gary Greene. He has some beautiful work and also instructional materials available on Youtube, ArtistsNetwork, Amazon and probably elsewhere. He does both colored pencil and watercolor pencil work. Watercolor pencils are a natural extension of straight colored pencil work. CP artists will sometimes melt their cp pasages with various solvents. Watercolor pencil uses a similar technique, except that the solvent is water. As I'm sure you're aware, it's the beauty of watercolor pencil (and also the use of other solvents with straight cp) that some passages will be dissolved and others left untreated, according to the discretion of the artist.

You can use any medium in a professional art career. The key here is not the medium used but your own creativity, skill, salesmanship and most of all, hard and persistent work. If your favorite medium is wc pencils, then dig in. It's a great medium to use.

Answer (score 1):

To go at this from a different angle 
My research for this question suggested that that **art** pencils were invented in the 1920's and watercolor or *water soluble* pencils were invented in the 1940's which means they have been around for less the 80 years.

Compare this to watercolor cakes being invented in by William Reeves in 1780 and watercolor *painting* came to western artists in the late 1400s. Meaning it's been an art form for over 600 years.

Oil painting, according to Wikipedia, has been around even longer.

> Although oil paint was first used for Buddhist paintings by Indian and Chinese painters in western Afghanistan sometime between the fifth and tenth centuries,[1] it did not gain popularity until the 15th century. Its practice may have migrated westward during the Middle Ages.

I hypothesize that watercolor pencils are relatively too new still. I know some watercolor painters use the pencils for fine details.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question but rather some things to draw your attention to:

**Artists using the same medium as you for inspiration**

Looking for inspiration by searching for artists that use the same medium as you do is the closest thing that comes to one’s mind (and it looks good on paper if you are an art teacher) but it is a rather superficial way of approaching the problem. Although you may both be using the same medium, you will most likely be approaching it in a very different way, and using it for very different purposes (have different subjects of interest to draw).

You should rather look for :

- thigs that explore your interests (in whatever  respect), be it in art or other areas of life
- things that have similar aesthetics to the one you appreciate, in any art medium (photography, cinema, oil painting) or in other areas of life

**Professional artists**

Whom do you consider professional artists? Those who are famous? Those who sell well? These things may have more to do with how well they promote their work, rather than the actual work. For this reason you should better look at separate artworks, rather than artists. (The internet is very convenient for that purpose, but you may want to consider deleting your cookies beforehand – you are looking for new inspiration, not the same things you are familiar with)

**Accepted art medium**

Generally speaking, any medium becomes respectable when there is an artist acclaimed by some critics (whose opinion you should better ignore; consider your own instead) that uses it.

Do you consider ballpoint pens a respectable drawing medium? Take a look at some [artwork made with ballpoint pens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballpoint_pen_artwork).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in the medium and long term (with tendency for this time to become shorter and shorter) the art market assigns the right price to the artwork. I wanted to know specifically the artwork which represent creativity and novelty and not just reproduce the reality images or is just pleasant picture.

It appears that one should seek the auction sites for the answer and there are some colored pencil artworks ineed:
http://www.sothebys.com/en/search-results.html?keyword=colored%20pencil%20on%20paper

e.g. Roy Lichtenstein colored pencil artwork was sold by 975.000 USD.

As usually, Christies has more modest lots:
http://www.christies.com/lotfinder/searchresults.aspx?sc_lang=en&lid=1&entry=colored%20pencil